# What is the meaning of "second_stage_batch_size*" setting when training with faster_rcnn_nas_coco model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

> I used Object detection API to train faster_rcnn_nas model.

But I got "out-of-memory" error, but when I add

```
second_stage_batch_size: 4
```

The above line of code solves my problem and I'm training now. But I wonder what is the meaning of the above line?

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py) is the definition of the above line.

But I don't really understand. Any one can explain for me?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py#L341), the "batch_size" is mostly terminology, the meaning is the number of proposals which contribute to the training process, i.e. those which are used for computing classification and bounding box regression and are contributing to the loss. It's therefore makes sense that if there are too much of those, your GPU will be out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

> The two stage architecture is a design choice made for region proposal
>   object detectors.

This results in a **two-stage training**, which is also something in the architecture of the R-FCN, which is originally adopted from the R-CNN implementation. The two-stage object detection consists of:

1. Region Proposal detection (1 Stage)
2. Region Classification. (2 Stage)

*The **second_stage_batch_size** is defined as,*
*the batch size used for computing the
classification and refined location loss of the box classifier. This "batch size" refers to the number of proposals selected as contributing
        to the loss function for any given image within the image batch and is
        only called "batch_size" due to terminology from the Faster R-CNN paper.*

*Note:* The out-of-memory error is likely due to hardware limitations or the amount of proposals of your first stage (try with a smaller batch-size for the first stage and / or for the second stage).

Comment: I used batch-size=1 and still get Out of memory without line "second_stage_batch_size: 4", so I wonder if I add that line, will it decrease the accuracy of the model when retrain? And why that line help me overcome "Out of memory" error?

Comment: Why I have to that if I can solve my problem by just adding "second_stage_batch_size: 4" to config file? But I just wonder will adding that line reduce the accuracy of the model when I retrain?

Comment: The second_stage_batch_size refers to the number of proposals for a given batch of images. If your batch_size is now 1 but you get too many proposals out of your first stage, you'll experience out of memory (as you reported). Setting second_stage_batch_size to 4 limits the amount of selected proposals and hinders the out of memory error. Smaller batch sizes usually generalize better, yet your training might take longer (accuracy should not be effected, but if it is running with 4 you can always try to run it with second_stage_batch_size of 8, 16, etc.). I hope this helped.

Comment: If this answers your question, you should accept it as the answer to close the question. Thanks.